# Date sorting in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, datetime

I am capturing dates in the following format:

```
Mon, February 14, 2011, 08:22:34 AM
```

When I sort posts by the most recent date/time by using ORDER BY date_time DESC, sometimes it sorts it correctly and sometimes it doesn't. So is there a better way to capture data so that the sorting will be done correctly?

For instance, work ten entries in a row it might sort properly, that is it will show the most recent posts first. Then after that it might put the most recent one at the very bottom

Comment: It should be done correctly via MySQL. In what instances is it not?

Comment: Agreed, @Aaron.  @OP, can you provide a simple test case to replicate your problem?

Comment: For instance, work ten entries in a row it might sort properly, that is it will show the most recent posts first.  Then after that it might put the most recent one at the very bottom....

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could post a sample of the database scheme.  Significantly, what type of field is the date value being stored it?  The mySQL date sorting functions are pretty reliable when used in combination with the date type field - a failure of these functions to properly sort would be a major bug for mySQL.  Since that probably isn't the case, we need more details from your specific project.

Comment: What's the data type of that field in PHP, and how are you storing those date strings? Are you parsing them in PHP or letting MySQL handle it?

Comment: Please provide the table DDL so that we can see the column, datatypes, constraints, etc.

Comment: Storing a date in a varchar field is a very bad idea. One of the reasons you just learned for yourself. Change your table and store it in a `date` column and you'll have no problems with sorting

Comment: date('D,F j, Y, h:i:s A'); thats how i am timestamping it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name should i just use datetime?

Comment: See the answers below.  You should change the field type, or use CAST to convert it.  The date sorting in mySQL is accurate when the field is of the proper type.

Comment: I guess or i can just sort by the #id ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per discussion on OP, you are storing the date as a string.  MySQL has many date sorting functions that can sort accurately, but the must be used in conjunction with a DATE type field.  You should either convert the field type to date/datetime, or perform a `cast` function to turn them into date types for the purpose of sorting.  Like this:

```
SELECT CAST(datefield as date) AS date_format ORDER BY date_format DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using a DATETIME field instead of a VARCHAR field for storing dates...

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

This will allow you to sort correctly as well as use MySQL datetime functions in queries on your datetime fields.

Answer (score 1):

Are you capturing the date in that format, or using some function like time()? If you sort by a date that is composed by both characters and numbers instead of only numeric-incrementing value, it will bring problems when sorting the entries.

Please correct me if I understood you wrong.

edit: if you want to avoid extra load on the server, you can create a varchar field which contains the processed date (the one you have right now), and a new int one you can use for saving the time(); and sorting the entries by date.

Comment: date('D,F j, Y, h:i:s A');  thats what i am using

Comment: You can still use that format and save it in the dB if you're willing to sacrifice a little bit more of a toll on the DB. But if you want to sort by date, you ought to use a function like time(http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php).

Answer (score 1):

Based on you saying that the field is a varchar, I assume that you are getting an ASCII sort of the strings in the field.  When the sort order is not as you expect, check for things like upper and lower case, etc.

If you want to sort dates it is best to use a datatime datatype.

Comment: DO i have to delete all info and then re-add it for it to sort properly, because i just changed the field type and it still shows it the same way.

Comment: I would probably create a new datatime field and run an update to copy the varchar value from the old field into the datatime field.  You will have to do a to_date() on it and then check the data.  Later, once happy its worked, drop the old field.